# Android Spinner Control

Tags: android, spinner

Is there a simple spinner control in android with a text view increment and dicrement button. Pressing the button add or subtracts from the value displayed in the textview. I have been searching for such, but have not been able to find one.

Kind Regards

Comment: what you are searching for is the NumberPicker

Comment: You can build it on you own. Just define a custom layout for your spinner items and implement a Adapter which uses it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [NumberPicker](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html) if your target API is above 11.